# Tab key behavior on HTML Table

Tags: html, browser, html-table, focus

I have a HTML Table with 5 rows and 5 columns. Now when the user starts filling in the Data, and wants to navigate from One cell to another, they clicks on tab and the cursor moves horizontally.

Instead of Horizontal, I want to move vertically. Like shown below in Image. This is very tricky as we want to override the basic OS? Browser functionality.

[image]

Comment: Please post relevant code or create a jsfiddle so that we can help you efficiently

Answer (score 2):

The global attribute [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex):

> The `tabindex` content attribute allows authors to control whether an element is supposed to be focusable, whether it is supposed to be reachable using sequential focus navigation, and **what is to be the relative order of the element for the purposes of sequential focus navigation**.

The value must be an integer (you need values greater than 0; see the linked spec for details).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use javascript onkeypress events to then give the next cell down focus. `onkeypress="if(event.keycode == 8) {document.getElementById('NEXT CELL DOWN').focus()"}` In this example 8 is the tab keycode. NEXT CELL DOWN could be hard coded for each cell or you could use an algorithm based on the current cell ID to move it to the next cell ID. For instance if tab is pressed on cell 1 the next cell could be cell1++. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let me try it and get back to you

Comment: Why not just use `tabindex`? There is no need for JavaScript here - and even if you want/need to use it you should really separate your JS code from the presentation layer for the sake of maintainability.

Comment: @acme I hadn't come across the tabindex attribute but I agree sounds like a better option :)